# Azure AD Enterprise Applications - reply url?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Had an app listed in 'enterprise applications' (publisher is 'Microsoft Accounts'), it is not showing in 'app registrations', having a few questions,

1. why the application is shown in 'enterprise applications' but not in 'app registrations'?
2. where do I know/configure the replyURL for the app?
3. how to grant the access to other apps (e.g. graph) there seems nowhere in the permission tab to grant permissions

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Enterprise Applications" are the [Service Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects) in your AAD Tenant.

They are not really meant to be configured in the way you are describing, rather they should act as an artifact of the Application Objects you use regularly.

If you are looking to configure an application's Reply URL and Permissions, you should create a brand new Application Object using the "App Registrations" blade.

Comment: This is not how it worked in the past, and every time I create one under App Registrations it adds it to Enterprise apps and thus I can no longer add new reply urls going forward. Something is really wrong with this.

Comment: Hi James, it seems like you are running into an issue creating apps, but we can't really help you in the comment section. Open a new post with your problems and myself and others can take a look and try to figure out a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949176/azure-active-directory-signin-apps-always-create-enterprise-app-with-no-ability

Answer (score 2):

Adding second answer to [@Shawn Tabrizi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396977/shawn-tabrizi) 's.

> 1.why the application is shown in 'enterprise applications' but not in 'app registrations'?

According to your post, I assume that the app is published by Microsoft Corporation. This kind app is added **from the gallery**. In gallery, there are many apps which are published by their companies. Enterprise apps are apps that are deployed and used within your organization and you can manage single sign-on settings for them by azure portal.

> 2.where do I know/configure the replyURL for the app?

If your you want to add **your own app** and integrate it with Azure AD, you need to register the app in App registrations. Also, if you grant permissions to your App,it will occurs in Enterprise applications.

> 3.how to grant the access to other apps (e.g. graph) there seems nowhere in the permission tab to grant permissions.

If your app is added from gallery, you cannot configured the Reply URL. You can only configure your own app in Application registrations.

Comment: Hi, @TOMMY WANG , If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer to help more people. Thanks!