# Azure Active Directory Signin Apps Always Create Enterprise App with no ability to set replyUrls

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In the past there was both the separate website AND the Azure classic portal for managing Signin Apps. In the Classic portal it would give you the ability to edit the ReplyUrls.

In the new portal no matter how you create an app (Enterprise or Application Registration) you can't edit your ReplyUrls from the UI. (With Application you can set them the first time but then they don't show up in the Application list from then on so it's impossible to edit them)

Meanwhile these same apps can have their replyUrls updated using Powershell without any problem.

To me this is a blocker bug, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?  I've successfully gotten only 1 application to show up under application registrations. All others including ones created back in the Azure Classic day show up in Enterprise applications without even the Sign On Option showing up in the list of options for the application per the instructions on Microsoft's website.

I can private message an app Id as an example.

Comment: Are you saying you are unable to access this UI? https://imgur.com/a/1U9QxnA

Comment: Yes. None of the apps show in there even if created there or using search by id. And enterprise doesn't have those options at all.

Comment: I just added a new image to the bottom of the gallery, which shows I was able to create a new app, just now, and [it shows up in the UX](https://imgur.com/vMhgDSH). Send me mail at shtabriz at microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks. See the checked answer.  The worst part about the horrible UI is that search doesn't even override the filter so you'd never know that the app you created under your Azure AD solely for sign-in is there, but under all apps even though it's yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user experience of the Azure portal changed for the worse (in my opinion).
I also had trouble finding my old apps... turns out they are now "hidden" by default.

> they don't show up in the Application list from then on so it's impossible to edit them)

You will find them under "all apps".
[image]

Comment: Wow! You're right, that is truly aweful! Especially considering that the app I was looking for is MY APP because it shows up in enterprise applications.  They really need to fix this so enterprise applications properly has reply urls under it AND fix this UI too if there are going to be separate ones!