# How to fix "Destination URL, which is treated as Reply URL for enabling Microsoft Azure Authentication, is missing"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

While trying to publish the Blazor Server Side sample (preview 7) with Organizational Authentication I get the error message that it can't find the Destination URL/Reply URL.

I have tried changing the values for reply URLS, but as I fear the problem is that something is missing in the sample code, this has had no affect. I am not sure where this reply URL should be set in the sample code for it to work. So under the assumption that this is what the real problem is, I guess what I am really wondering is where and how do I set these values in Blazor (Server side)?

To recreate the problem I am seeing simply create a new Blazor Server side project and choose "Work and School Accounts" under Authentication. Choose "Cloud S- Single organization" and select your Domain. Click "OK". And "Create"

Then when the project has been created, try to publish it to azure with the publish dialog and this is the result I get:
[image: Publish Dialog]
[image: Create App service]
[image: Choose account to authenticate]
[image: Error message]

When I try the samples with the other authentication methods/no authentication publishing to Azure from VS2019 Preview works fine. I think maybe it's because when I choose the sample with Authentication: Work or School Accounts it makes a Enterprise Application in Azure that it uses for the sign in, but when I publish the app it makes a new application under "App registrations" inn Azure. So then I think I have one application for signing in and one where the actual site is located and they of course do not talk to each other. I don't immediately see how I can merge these two. The Enterprise Application does not allow me to change the reply url, which is set to localhost.

Comment: OK, I can confirm what you see. Your answer may be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923398/azure-ad-enterprise-applications-reply-url

Comment: The publish wizzard leaves me with an Enterprise app where the URL is localhost and not editable.

Comment: Does publishing work for you when you have chosen server side with "Work/school account" Authentication?

Comment: To be clear, I am able to publish it, but when I do I get an error message saying that the reply URLs don't match. This I think is related to the error indication I get before publishing where it says that the Destination URL is missing.

Comment: This does not answer my question and I am still not able to publish Server Side Blazor with "Work or School" Authentication checked. Still receive reply URL error.

Comment: You probably have to [edit] and add the relevant code, including the ADAzure configuration. Replace the real credentials with XXXXX or so.

Comment: But for a solution you will probably have to be in Azure Portal. Also tell us what is configured there, maybe add some screenshots. I did take a look last Friday but things had changed a lot since I last used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I blundert my way through this and got it working.

- after you published with the wizzard, go to Azure Portal, AAD
- Under Enterprise Apps there should be an entry created for your app

  - I couldn't get that configured, forget it
- So, click [+] New Application (from Enterprise App and follow the steps)

  - this takes you to App Registrations (you could go there directly)
  - create a new one, follow the steps
  - under Overview of your new App Reg, you will see

    - Application (client) ID
    - Directory (tenant) ID
    - copy both values to your AppSettings.json , overwrite what is there
  - Under the new App Reg, go to Authentication

    - Add the redirect URI  `https://_yoursitename_.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`
    - scroll down and check [x] Id Tokens
    - click Save
- Publish again

Run your app

Comment: Thank you Henk, this was the solution. In the publish dialog in VS2019 it still had the error message that destination URL was missing, but publishing still worked and everything now works as expected! If I had more reputation I would give you +1 :)